# Ag-grid select all checkbox causes application to hang

Tags: ag-grid-react

I'm using Ag-grid-react (v.23.1.0) to display around 500 rows using the default client side model.  The first column has headerCheckboxSelection. The problem is when user clicks on the 'Select All' checkbox in the header of the first column, it causes the application to hang.  Please could someone help?

Column definition:

```
{
    field: 'selectItem',
    headerName: '',
    headerCheckboxSelection: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am facing same issue. So far I turned off animations.

```
animateRows={false}
```

Check this: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-performance/.
I will update my response if learn something new